# Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = \frac{1}{3^{n+5}}$ is bounded, find its supremum and its infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $A = (x_n)$ be a sequence that defined as $x_n = \frac{1}{3^{n+5}}$.
Show that $A$ is bounded and find it's supremum and the infimum.

**Attempt:**
First, I claim that $A$ is a decreasing sequence. I show this by induction as follows.
To show: $x_{n+1} < x_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. Indeed, this is true for $n=1$. Now, assume that for $n=k$, it's also true; that's, $x_{k+1} < x_k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z^+$. Then,
$x_{k+2} = \frac{1}{3^{(k+2)+5}} = \frac{1}{3^{k+7}} < \frac{1}{3^{k+6}} = \frac{1}{3^{(k+1)+5}} = x_{k+1}$. Hence, $x_{k+1} < x_k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z^+$. Therefore, $x_{n+1} < x_n$
for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. Thus, $A$ is a decreasing sequence. $\Box$

Now, back to the problem. To show: A is bounded. Since $A$ is a decreasing sequence and tending to $0$, then $A$ is bounded below by $0$. Next, it's clear that for all $s \in A$, we have
$s \le \frac{1}{3^6}$, which is happenned if and only if $n=1$. Hence, by definition, $A$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{3^6}$. Therefore, $A$ is bounded.

Next, we find the supremum and the infimum of $A$. Indeed, $\inf A = 0$ and $\sup A = \frac{1}{3^6}$.
To show: $\inf A = 0$. Let $m$ be the another lower bound of $A$ and suppose that $0 \lt m$.
Then, since $A$ is a decreasing and bounded sequence, there exist an element of $A$, say $r$,
such that $r \lt m$. A contradiction with the definition of a lower bound. Hence, we must have
$m \le 0$ and thus, $\inf A = 0$.

To show: $\sup A = \frac{1}{3^6}$. Let $M$ be the another upper bound of $A$ and suppose that $M \lt \frac{1}{3^6}$. Then, since $A$ is a decreasing and bounded sequence, there exist an element of $A$, say $s$, such that $M \lt s$. A contradiction with the definition of a upper bound. Hence, we must have
$\frac{1}{3^6} \le M$ and thus, $\sup A = \frac{1}{3^6}$.

Am I true? Anyone please correct me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the initial value of $n$ ?

Comment: absolutely from $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For induction part, base case is OK. But then inductive hypothesis case should also mention that $n=k\gt 1$. Then Induction part is OK. 
To prove $\inf A=0$, you have mentioned that "Let $m$ be the another lower bound of A and suppose that $0<m$. Then, since $A$ is a decreasing and bounded sequence, there exist an element of $A$, say $r$, such that $r<m$..." Question is why does such $r$ exist? Example: The sequence $(y_n)=(2+1/n)$ is also decreasing and $0$ and $2$ are lower bounds but there is no $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $y_k\lt 2$. Similarly for supremum case. 
In order to find $\sup A$ and $\inf A$, you may proceed as below also: 
Let $m\gt 0$ be a lower bound for $A$, then by Archimedean property of real numbers $\exists N $ such that $1/N\lt m$. Now choose $n$ so large that $3^{n+5}\gt N$ and therefore, $1/3^{n+5}\lt m$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $\inf A=0$.

Let $l\lt 1/3^6$ be an upper bound for $A$. Hence, $1/3^{n+5}\le l\lt 1/3^6$ for all $n$. Clearly, $n=1$ gives $l=1/3^6$, which is a contradiction.Therefore, $\sup A=1/3^6$ as $1/3^6$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in what you wrote, and discussing the growth and the limit is not really necessary.

Obviously $x_n\ge\color{blue}0$, and this is a lower bound. Also $x_n=\dfrac1{3^{n+5}}=\dfrac1{3^{n-1}}\dfrac1{3^{1+5}}\le\color{red}{\dfrac1{3^{1+5}}}$ and this is an upper bound.

It turns out that these bounds are at the same time the infimum and supremum.

- Infimum: we have $\color{blue}0\le x_n$. Now let $t>0$. We certainly have $x_n=\dfrac1{3^{n+5}}<t$ for some $n$ large enough, because this condition is equivalent to $-(n+5)<\log_3 t$.
- Supremum: we have $\color{red}{\dfrac1{3^{1+5}}}\ge x_n$ and $\dfrac1{3^{1+5}}= x_1$. The supremum is also a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the infimum is wrong, as the existence of such an $r$ does not follow from decreasing and bounded. A better proof would be that if $m > 0$ is a lower bound of the sequence, then choose $n > - \log_{3}(m) - 5$ which leads to $x_n < m$, a contradiction to $m$ being a lower bound. This $n$ can easily be found by working backwards. Since $0$ is obviously a lower bound, $0$ is the infimum.

Likewise, the existence of such an $s$ for the supremum is not guaranteed as written. This one is easy; since the sequence is decreasing, $x_n \leq x_1 = \frac{1}{3^6}$, meaning $\frac{1}{3^6}$ is an upper bound and is the best such one as it is the value of $x_1$. The rest of the proof is fine.

Comment: so, the conclusion is, my proof in the infimum and supremum part are wrong, right ?

Comment: Yes, your $m$ and $s$ values don't follow from what you wrote, so it is wrong.

Comment: Ok sir thanks for the advice.